# Отладка скриптов без Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, отладка

Есть скрипт выполняющий `Ajax` запросы. Для его работы не нужен никакой интерфейс в браузере, но зато нужен node сервер.

Тем не менее сейчас я использую node-сервер + браузер (для отладки), и это не очень удобно (как минимум потому что в папке проекта лежит лишний файл).

Знаю что консоль отладки браузера можно заменить с помощью `node` (такая штука есть в VS Code, который я не использую).

Как можно реализовать отладку и сервер на node, чтобы избежать консоли браузера и лишних файлов.

Comment: а Вы запрос не с браузера делаете?

Answer (score 0):

Для отладки вы можете использовать [debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html). Для более детального ознакомления, см. [руководство по отладке в node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).

> Это руководство поможет вам начать отладку приложений `Node.js` и скриптов.

Comment: Фактически мне нужна отладка обычного (не нодовского) кода. Ваш вариант подойдет?

Comment: см. и читай  обновление

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте VisualStudioCode!

В vscode есть debugConsole для изменения всяких переменных в процессе running'а скрипта, terminal для ввода-вывода. можно debug'ить браузер(Chrome) и node.js(я попробовал поставиь breakpoint в скрипте, и добавить его в index.html, и обоже, дебаг сразу и в index.html и script.js), ведь для запуска вашего кода вы используете node? так что дебаг node.js вам подойдет.

(на vscode я случайно наткнулся, в общем, отличный редактор кода, подсвечивание ошибок, всякие snippet'ы и тд)

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm, свой Debugger и своя Console запускает node открывает браузер но вывод идет в свою консоль, все это без перезагрузки страницы (точнее с Auto-reload)

https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/